# What is the name of the font that the Windows 7 Command Line uses?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, fonts

I'd like to know the name of the font that is referred to as the "Raster 8x12" font in the Windows 7 command line, does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Open the command prompt.

Right click on the title bar, select properties.

Select the Font tab. Read the name of the font.

[image: Command Line Font Properties]

Set it to whatever you want if you don't like it...

EDIT:

It's not that easy to install a new raster font for Windows 10 command prompt. I downloaded one and installed it, but it didn't show up. I found an old registry hack which I followed but the font still didn't show up.

Eventually I found [this page](https://technicalustad.com/custom-font-in-command-prompt/), which only talks about TrueType fonts. It notes that only Monospaced fonts (i.e. fixed width) are supported, so bad luck using Comic Sans. It then lists some other restrictions on possible fonts. Finally it uses the same registry hack I found originally and tells you to reboot (which the original one I followed didn't so I haven't, and I can't right now).

It also tells you open the command prompt as Admin to change the font.

Good luck!

Comment: It's set to "Raster fonts" 8x12, searching online doesn't yield any downloadable fonts, which is in fact the point of my question.

Comment: OK. (That's not what the title of the question was but never mind.) I did a search on 'raster fonts windows' and at least 4 of the first 5 results offered downloads. I'm having a look at one of them. Wait a few minutes and I'll edit the answer with what I find out.